# How can I migrate data in index.html to a controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I have an angular custom directive called 'workHistory'. It's sole purpose is to display a d3 chart. For the purpose of this question, d3 knowledge is not required.

Basically, the directive runs how to should. For cleaner setup, I'd like to place the data that's currently in the index.html into its own controller. The problem I'm having is setting the controller up properly.

**index.html** (data i'd like migrated is near the bottom under "values"

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en" ng-app="webApp">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>My Portfolio</title>

        <!--Stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/d3.tree.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.0/select2.min.css"/>
        <!--Libraries -->
        <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-loader/angular-loader.min.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.0/select2.min.js"></script>
        <!--Module -->
        <script src="scripts/modules/module.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/modules/d3.module.js"></script>
        <!--Controllers -->
        <script src="scripts/controllers/mainHeroController.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/workHistoryController.js"></script>
        <!--Directives-->
        <script src="scripts/directives/mainHero.directive.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/directives/mainNavbar.directive.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/directives/workHistory.directive.js"></script>
        <script>
var values={
     "name": "flare",
     "children": [
      {
       "name": "analytics",
       "children": [
        {
         "name": "cluster",
         "children": [
          {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
          {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
          {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
          {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
         ]
        },
        {
         "name": "graph",
         "children": [
          {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
          {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
          {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
          {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
          {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
         ]
        },
        {
         "name": "optimization",
         "children": [
          {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
         ]
        }
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "animate",
       "children": [
        {"name": "Easing", "size": 17010},
        {"name": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842},
        {
         "name": "interpolate",
         "children": [
          {"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983},
          {"name": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047},
          {"name": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375},
          {"name": "Interpolator", "size": 8746},
          {"name": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202},
          {"name": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382},
          {"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629},
          {"name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675},
          {"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042}
         ]
        },
        {"name": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041},
        {"name": "Parallel", "size": 5176},
        {"name": "Pause", "size": 449},
        {"name": "Scheduler", "size": 5593},
        {"name": "Sequence", "size": 5534},
        {"name": "Transition", "size": 9201},
        {"name": "Transitioner", "size": 19975},
        {"name": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116},
        {"name": "Tween", "size": 6006}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "data",
       "children": [
        {
         "name": "converters",
         "children": [
          {"name": "Converters", "size": 721},
          {"name": "DelimitedTextConverter", "size": 4294},
          {"name": "GraphMLConverter", "size": 9800},
          {"name": "IDataConverter", "size": 1314},
          {"name": "JSONConverter", "size": 2220}
         ]
        },
        {"name": "DataField", "size": 1759},
        {"name": "DataSchema", "size": 2165},
        {"name": "DataSet", "size": 586},
        {"name": "DataSource", "size": 3331},
        {"name": "DataTable", "size": 772},
        {"name": "DataUtil", "size": 3322}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "display",
       "children": [
        {"name": "DirtySprite", "size": 8833},
        {"name": "LineSprite", "size": 1732},
        {"name": "RectSprite", "size": 3623},
        {"name": "TextSprite", "size": 10066}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "flex",
       "children": [
        {"name": "FlareVis", "size": 4116}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "physics",
       "children": [
        {"name": "DragForce", "size": 1082},
        {"name": "GravityForce", "size": 1336},
        {"name": "IForce", "size": 319},
        {"name": "NBodyForce", "size": 10498},
        {"name": "Particle", "size": 2822},
        {"name": "Simulation", "size": 9983},
        {"name": "Spring", "size": 2213},
        {"name": "SpringForce", "size": 1681}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "query",
       "children": [
        {"name": "AggregateExpression", "size": 1616},
        {"name": "And", "size": 1027},
        {"name": "Arithmetic", "size": 3891},
        {"name": "Average", "size": 891},
        {"name": "BinaryExpression", "size": 2893},
        {"name": "Comparison", "size": 5103},
        {"name": "CompositeExpression", "size": 3677},
        {"name": "Count", "size": 781},
        {"name": "DateUtil", "size": 4141},
        {"name": "Distinct", "size": 933},
        {"name": "Expression", "size": 5130},
        {"name": "ExpressionIterator", "size": 3617},
        {"name": "Fn", "size": 3240},
        {"name": "If", "size": 2732},
        {"name": "IsA", "size": 2039},
        {"name": "Literal", "size": 1214},
        {"name": "Match", "size": 3748},
        {"name": "Maximum", "size": 843},
        {
         "name": "methods",
         "children": [
          {"name": "add", "size": 593},
          {"name": "and", "size": 330},
          {"name": "average", "size": 287},
          {"name": "count", "size": 277},
          {"name": "distinct", "size": 292},
          {"name": "div", "size": 595},
          {"name": "eq", "size": 594},
          {"name": "fn", "size": 460},
          {"name": "gt", "size": 603},
          {"name": "gte", "size": 625},
          {"name": "iff", "size": 748},
          {"name": "isa", "size": 461},
          {"name": "lt", "size": 597},
          {"name": "lte", "size": 619},
          {"name": "max", "size": 283},
          {"name": "min", "size": 283},
          {"name": "mod", "size": 591},
          {"name": "mul", "size": 603},
          {"name": "neq", "size": 599},
          {"name": "not", "size": 386},
          {"name": "or", "size": 323},
          {"name": "orderby", "size": 307},
          {"name": "range", "size": 772},
          {"name": "select", "size": 296},
          {"name": "stddev", "size": 363},
          {"name": "sub", "size": 600},
          {"name": "sum", "size": 280},
          {"name": "update", "size": 307},
          {"name": "variance", "size": 335},
          {"name": "where", "size": 299},
          {"name": "xor", "size": 354},
          {"name": "_", "size": 264}
         ]
        },
        {"name": "Minimum", "size": 843},
        {"name": "Not", "size": 1554},
        {"name": "Or", "size": 970},
        {"name": "Query", "size": 13896},
        {"name": "Range", "size": 1594},
        {"name": "StringUtil", "size": 4130},
        {"name": "Sum", "size": 791},
        {"name": "Variable", "size": 1124},
        {"name": "Variance", "size": 1876},
        {"name": "Xor", "size": 1101}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "scale",
       "children": [
        {"name": "IScaleMap", "size": 2105},
        {"name": "LinearScale", "size": 1316},
        {"name": "LogScale", "size": 3151},
        {"name": "OrdinalScale", "size": 3770},
        {"name": "QuantileScale", "size": 2435},
        {"name": "QuantitativeScale", "size": 4839},
        {"name": "RootScale", "size": 1756},
        {"name": "Scale", "size": 4268},
        {"name": "ScaleType", "size": 1821},
        {"name": "TimeScale", "size": 5833}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "util",
       "children": [
        {"name": "Arrays", "size": 8258},
        {"name": "Colors", "size": 10001},
        {"name": "Dates", "size": 8217},
        {"name": "Displays", "size": 12555},
        {"name": "Filter", "size": 2324},
        {"name": "Geometry", "size": 10993},
        {
         "name": "heap",
         "children": [
          {"name": "FibonacciHeap", "size": 9354},
          {"name": "HeapNode", "size": 1233}
         ]
        },
        {"name": "IEvaluable", "size": 335},
        {"name": "IPredicate", "size": 383},
        {"name": "IValueProxy", "size": 874},
        {
         "name": "math",
         "children": [
          {"name": "DenseMatrix", "size": 3165},
          {"name": "IMatrix", "size": 2815},
          {"name": "SparseMatrix", "size": 3366}
         ]
        },
        {"name": "Maths", "size": 17705},
        {"name": "Orientation", "size": 1486},
        {
         "name": "palette",
         "children": [
          {"name": "ColorPalette", "size": 6367},
          {"name": "Palette", "size": 1229},
          {"name": "ShapePalette", "size": 2059},
          {"name": "SizePalette", "size": 2291}
         ]
        },
        {"name": "Property", "size": 5559},
        {"name": "Shapes", "size": 19118},
        {"name": "Sort", "size": 6887},
        {"name": "Stats", "size": 6557},
        {"name": "Strings", "size": 22026}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "vis",
       "children": [
        {
         "name": "axis",
         "children": [
          {"name": "Axes", "size": 1302},
          {"name": "Axis", "size": 24593},
          {"name": "AxisGridLine", "size": 652},
          {"name": "AxisLabel", "size": 636},
          {"name": "CartesianAxes", "size": 6703}
         ]
        },
        {
         "name": "controls",
         "children": [
          {"name": "AnchorControl", "size": 2138},
          {"name": "ClickControl", "size": 3824},
          {"name": "Control", "size": 1353},
          {"name": "ControlList", "size": 4665},
          {"name": "DragControl", "size": 2649},
          {"name": "ExpandControl", "size": 2832},
          {"name": "HoverControl", "size": 4896},
          {"name": "IControl", "size": 763},
          {"name": "PanZoomControl", "size": 5222},
          {"name": "SelectionControl", "size": 7862},
          {"name": "TooltipControl", "size": 8435}
         ]
        },
        {
         "name": "data",
         "children": [
          {"name": "Data", "size": 20544},
          {"name": "DataList", "size": 19788},
          {"name": "DataSprite", "size": 10349},
          {"name": "EdgeSprite", "size": 3301},
          {"name": "NodeSprite", "size": 19382},
          {
           "name": "render",
           "children": [
            {"name": "ArrowType", "size": 698},
            {"name": "EdgeRenderer", "size": 5569},
            {"name": "IRenderer", "size": 353},
            {"name": "ShapeRenderer", "size": 2247}
           ]
          },
          {"name": "ScaleBinding", "size": 11275},
          {"name": "Tree", "size": 7147},
          {"name": "TreeBuilder", "size": 9930}
         ]
        },
        {
         "name": "events",
         "children": [
          {"name": "DataEvent", "size": 2313},
          {"name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 1880},
          {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 1701},
          {"name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 1117}
         ]
        },
        {
         "name": "legend",
         "children": [
          {"name": "Legend", "size": 20859},
          {"name": "LegendItem", "size": 4614},
          {"name": "LegendRange", "size": 10530}
         ]
        },
        {
         "name": "operator",
         "children": [
          {
           "name": "distortion",
           "children": [
            {"name": "BifocalDistortion", "size": 4461},
            {"name": "Distortion", "size": 6314},
            {"name": "FisheyeDistortion", "size": 3444}
           ]
          },
          {
           "name": "encoder",
           "children": [
            {"name": "ColorEncoder", "size": 3179},
            {"name": "Encoder", "size": 4060},
            {"name": "PropertyEncoder", "size": 4138},
            {"name": "ShapeEncoder", "size": 1690},
            {"name": "SizeEncoder", "size": 1830}
           ]
          },
          {
           "name": "filter",
           "children": [
            {"name": "FisheyeTreeFilter", "size": 5219},
            {"name": "GraphDistanceFilter", "size": 3165},
            {"name": "VisibilityFilter", "size": 3509}
           ]
          },
          {"name": "IOperator", "size": 1286},
          {
           "name": "label",
           "children": [
            {"name": "Labeler", "size": 9956},
            {"name": "RadialLabeler", "size": 3899},
            {"name": "StackedAreaLabeler", "size": 3202}
           ]
          },
          {
           "name": "layout",
           "children": [
            {"name": "AxisLayout", "size": 6725},
            {"name": "BundledEdgeRouter", "size": 3727},
            {"name": "CircleLayout", "size": 9317},
            {"name": "CirclePackingLayout", "size": 12003},
            {"name": "DendrogramLayout", "size": 4853},
            {"name": "ForceDirectedLayout", "size": 8411},
            {"name": "IcicleTreeLayout", "size": 4864},
            {"name": "IndentedTreeLayout", "size": 3174},
            {"name": "Layout", "size": 7881},
            {"name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "size": 12870},
            {"name": "PieLayout", "size": 2728},
            {"name": "RadialTreeLayout", "size": 12348},
            {"name": "RandomLayout", "size": 870},
            {"name": "StackedAreaLayout", "size": 9121},
            {"name": "TreeMapLayout", "size": 9191}
           ]
          },
          {"name": "Operator", "size": 2490},
          {"name": "OperatorList", "size": 5248},
          {"name": "OperatorSequence", "size": 4190},
          {"name": "OperatorSwitch", "size": 2581},
          {"name": "SortOperator", "size": 2023}
         ]
        },
        {"name": "Visualization", "size": 16540}
       ]
      }
     ]
    };

    </script>
    </head>

     <!--Main Landing Page-->    
    <body ng-app="webApp">
        <main-navbar></main-navbar>
        <main-hero></main-hero>
        <div id="container1" ng-init="chart=[10, 20, 30]"> 
            <h3 id="tree-title">Work History</h3>
                <work-history chart-data="chart"></work-history>
            </div>
        <div id="container2">
            Container 2
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I have tried the **controller** setup like so:

```
(function() 
{

'use strict'

angular
    .module('webApp')
    .controller('WorkHistoryController', WorkHistoryController);

WorkHistoryController.$inject = ['$scope'];

function WorkHistoryController($scope) 
    {            
     console.log($scope);
      $scope.values = $scope.values || {};    
      $scope.values = {
         "name": "Work History",
         "children": [
          {
           "name": "analytics",
           "children": [
            {
             "name": "cluster",
             "children": [
              {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
              {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
              {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
              {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
             ]
            },
            {
             "name": "graph",
             "children": [
              {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
              {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
              {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
              {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
              {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
             ]
            },
            {
             "name": "optimization",
             "children": [
              {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
             ]
            }
           ]
          },
          {
           "name": "animate",
           "children": [
            {"name": "Easing", "size": 17010},
            {"name": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842},
            {
             "name": "interpolate",
             "children": [
              {"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983},
              {"name": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047},
              {"name": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375},
              {"name": "Interpolator", "size": 8746},
              {"name": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202},
              {"name": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382},
              {"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629},
              {"name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675},
              {"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042}
             ]
            },
            {"name": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041},
            {"name": "Parallel", "size": 5176},
            {"name": "Pause", "size": 449},
            {"name": "Scheduler", "size": 5593},
            {"name": "Sequence", "size": 5534},
            {"name": "Transition", "size": 9201},
            {"name": "Transitioner", "size": 19975},
            {"name": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116},
            {"name": "Tween", "size": 6006}
           ]
          },
          {
           "name": "data",
           "children": [
            {
             "name": "converters",
             "children": [
              {"name": "Converters", "size": 721},
              {"name": "DelimitedTextConverter", "size": 4294},
              {"name": "GraphMLConverter", "size": 9800},
              {"name": "IDataConverter", "size": 1314},
              {"name": "JSONConverter", "size": 2220}
             ]
            },
            {"name": "DataField", "size": 1759},
            {"name": "DataSchema", "size": 2165},
            {"name": "DataSet", "size": 586},
            {"name": "DataSource", "size": 3331},
            {"name": "DataTable", "size": 772},
            {"name": "DataUtil", "size": 3322}
           ]
          },
            {"name": "IEvaluable", "size": 335},
            {"name": "IPredicate", "size": 383},
            {"name": "IValueProxy", "size": 874},
            {
             "name": "math",
             "children": [
              {"name": "DenseMatrix", "size": 3165},
              {"name": "IMatrix", "size": 2815},
              {"name": "SparseMatrix", "size": 3366}
             ]
            },
            {"name": "Maths", "size": 17705},
            {"name": "Orientation", "size": 1486},
            {
             "name": "palette",
             "children": [
              {"name": "ColorPalette", "size": 6367},
              {"name": "Palette", "size": 1229},
              {"name": "ShapePalette", "size": 2059},
              {"name": "SizePalette", "size": 2291}
             ]
            },
            {"name": "Property", "size": 5559},
            {"name": "Shapes", "size": 19118},
            {"name": "Sort", "size": 6887},
            {"name": "Stats", "size": 6557},
            {"name": "Strings", "size": 22026}
           ]
          },
          {
           "name": "vis",
           "children": [
            {
             "name": "axis",
             "children": [
              {"name": "Axes", "size": 1302},
              {"name": "Axis", "size": 24593},
              {"name": "AxisGridLine", "size": 652},
              {"name": "AxisLabel", "size": 636},
              {"name": "CartesianAxes", "size": 6703}
             ]
            },
            {
             "name": "controls",
             "children": [
              {"name": "AnchorControl", "size": 2138},
              {"name": "ClickControl", "size": 3824},
              {"name": "Control", "size": 1353},
              {"name": "ControlList", "size": 4665},
              {"name": "DragControl", "size": 2649},
              {"name": "ExpandControl", "size": 2832},
              {"name": "HoverControl", "size": 4896},
              {"name": "IControl", "size": 763},
              {"name": "PanZoomControl", "size": 5222},
              {"name": "SelectionControl", "size": 7862},
              {"name": "TooltipControl", "size": 8435}
             ]
            },
            {
             "name": "data",
             "children": [
              {"name": "Data", "size": 20544},
              {"name": "DataList", "size": 19788},
              {"name": "DataSprite", "size": 10349},
              {"name": "EdgeSprite", "size": 3301},
              {"name": "NodeSprite", "size": 19382},
              {
               "name": "render",
               "children": [
                {"name": "ArrowType", "size": 698},
                {"name": "EdgeRenderer", "size": 5569},
                {"name": "IRenderer", "size": 353},
                {"name": "ShapeRenderer", "size": 2247}
               ]
              },
              {"name": "ScaleBinding", "size": 11275},
              {"name": "Tree", "size": 7147},
              {"name": "TreeBuilder", "size": 9930}
             ]
            },
            {
             "name": "events",
             "children": [
              {"name": "DataEvent", "size": 2313},
              {"name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 1880},
              {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 1701},
              {"name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 1117}
             ]
            },
            {
             "name": "legend",
             "children": [
              {"name": "Legend", "size": 20859},
              {"name": "LegendItem", "size": 4614},
              {"name": "LegendRange", "size": 10530}
             ]
            },
            {
             "name": "operator",
             "children": [
              {
               "name": "distortion",
               "children": [
                {"name": "BifocalDistortion", "size": 4461},
                {"name": "Distortion", "size": 6314},
                {"name": "FisheyeDistortion", "size": 3444}
               ]
              },
              {
               "name": "encoder",
               "children": [
                {"name": "ColorEncoder", "size": 3179},
                {"name": "Encoder", "size": 4060},
                {"name": "PropertyEncoder", "size": 4138},
                {"name": "ShapeEncoder", "size": 1690},
                {"name": "SizeEncoder", "size": 1830}
               ]
              },
              {
               "name": "filter",
               "children": [
                {"name": "FisheyeTreeFilter", "size": 5219},
                {"name": "GraphDistanceFilter", "size": 3165},
                {"name": "VisibilityFilter", "size": 3509}
               ]
              },
              {"name": "IOperator", "size": 1286},
              {
               "name": "label",
               "children": [
                {"name": "Labeler", "size": 9956},
                {"name": "RadialLabeler", "size": 3899},
                {"name": "StackedAreaLabeler", "size": 3202}
               ]
              },
              {
               "name": "layout",
               "children": [
                {"name": "AxisLayout", "size": 6725},
                {"name": "BundledEdgeRouter", "size": 3727},
                {"name": "CircleLayout", "size": 9317},
                {"name": "CirclePackingLayout", "size": 12003},
                {"name": "DendrogramLayout", "size": 4853},
                {"name": "ForceDirectedLayout", "size": 8411},
                {"name": "IcicleTreeLayout", "size": 4864},
                {"name": "IndentedTreeLayout", "size": 3174},
                {"name": "Layout", "size": 7881},
                {"name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "size": 12870},
                {"name": "PieLayout", "size": 2728},
                {"name": "RadialTreeLayout", "size": 12348},
                {"name": "RandomLayout", "size": 870},
                {"name": "StackedAreaLayout", "size": 9121},
                {"name": "TreeMapLayout", "size": 9191}
               ]
              },
              {"name": "Operator", "size": 2490},
              {"name": "OperatorList", "size": 5248},
              {"name": "OperatorSequence", "size": 4190},
              {"name": "OperatorSwitch", "size": 2581},
              {"name": "SortOperator", "size": 2023}
             ]
            },
            {"name": "Visualization", "size": 16540}
           ]
          }
         ]
        };
    }
 })();
```

But nothing registers, how would one properly set up the controller to carry the "values" currently in index.html?

Comment: I can't see where you use the values structure in the HTML. surely you need to pass the data to D3 somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second `ng-app` from your `<body>` tag, you should only call it once. Instead use [`ng-controller`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController) to hook html element/s to a controller.

You should look at [Angular `ng` Directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive) like `ng-bind` or [interpolation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation). There are also more complex directives to display data from object or array structures.

This is a good overview, see usage section in https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Comment: Ideally - when using angular 1.5.x - you would be looking at the component syntax for the easiest change. I found this Todd Motto article a good one to understand: https://toddmotto.com/exploring-the-angular-1-5-component-method/

Otherwise: make sure you have all variables names correct: i see $scope.values - but also chart as the value passed into the workchart directive?